# How does Pandas Interpolate Time work?

Tags: python, pandas

How does Pandas Interpolate method = time function work? From my understanding, it sounds very similar to an Exponential Moving Average, but it gives me different results, even when I play around with the function parameters.

````py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index_date = pd.to_datetime(["2020-12-01", "2020-12-02", "2020-12-15", "2020-12-31"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,5,np.nan,15]}, index=index_date)
display(df.interpolate(method="time"))
display(df.ewm(com=0.3).mean()) 
```
````

Comment: Hint: $9.582759 \approx (13 \times 15 + 16 \times 5) / (13 + 16).$

Comment: @whuber Amazing thank you! If you put this as an answer I will accept it